# Destructuring first value of an array of objects in reduce method

Tags: javascript

Let's say you an array of objects, where you're reducing a property into one result separated by dashes, e.g:

```
const array = [
  { foo: "foo" },
  { foo: "foo" },
]
```

Should become the string:

```
foo-foo
```

If you're using the `reduce` method, you might do something like this:

```js
const array = [ { foo: "foo" }, { foo: "foo" }, { foo: "foo" } ];
const result = array.reduce( ( accumulator, { foo } ) => {
  return accumulator + "-" + foo;
} );

console.log( result );
```

However, the problem is that the default initial value (the first element of the array) is the entire first object, naturally resulting in `[object Object]-foo-foo`.

**Question is**: is there a simple way to, for example destructure, the initial value?

You can bypass the issue by, for example, using an `if`-statement specifically checking whether the accumulator is currently an object:

```js
const array = [ { foo: "foo" }, { foo: "foo" }, { foo: "foo" } ];
const result = array.reduce( ( accumulator, { foo } ) => {
  if ( accumulator.hasOwnProperty( "foo" ) ) {
    return accumulator.foo + "-" + foo;
  }
  return accumulator + "-" + foo;
} );

console.log( result );
```

However, I am interested in a simpler/prettier way of doing this, using less "arbitrary-looking" code, perhaps a way to do this using the actual `initialValue` argument of `reduce`.

**Note**: I am not looking for an answer to an actual real problem I am facing now (and thus not looking for alternative solutions such as `for let/of loops` or filtering the array), I am asking for the sake of learning more about the `reduce` method in these types of situations for future reference.

Comment: Why not just supply an initial value to `reduce`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map and join the items.

```js
var array = [{ foo: "foo" }, { foo: "foo" }, { foo: "foo" }],
    result = array
        .map(({ foo }) => foo)
        .join('-');

console.log(result);
```

A `reduce` approach with a check if a dash is necessary.

```js
var array = [{ foo: "foo" }, { foo: "foo" }, { foo: "foo" }],
    result = array.reduce((r, { foo }) => r + (r && '-') + foo, '');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think that OP only wants a reduce solution - as mentioned in their note.

Comment: Like Kobe said, I'm specifically looking for a reduce solution (out of interest/curiosity). Your reduce solution is great though, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the initial value to an empty string, and use a ternary to check if the string is empty, if true, then return only the `foo`, otherwise, return the `accumulator`, a dash, and `foo`:

```js
const array = [ { foo: "foo" }, { foo: "foo" }, { foo: "foo" } ];

const result = array.reduce((a, {foo}) => a ? `${a}-${foo}` : foo, '');

console.log(result);
```

We can be sure that on the initial loop that the ternary will return only `foo` as `''` evaluates to false.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. I hadn't thought of the fact that the initial value `""` would of course equate to a falsy value and could therefore easily be used for a conditional. (Upvoted, but I'll have to give the best answer to Scholz for the lovely `&&` operator)